# Get output of all dcu files in delphi 5

Tags: ide, mapping, delphi-5, borland-c++, dcu

Is there any way to map all .dcu files (including paths) in Delphi 5 project (need this before transferring it Delphi 10)? The problem is that there are a few libraries with the same names that are in use by different files in the project, so need to know exactly where the actual data comes from.

Is there any way to see the dependences list while compiling in IDE - Borland Delphi 5?

We've been searching over internet for solution, but didn't get to any practical solution.

1. File .map maps only .res and .dfm files. So this can give some insight but definitely not all.
2. Tried third party programs as GExpert (gives uses' paths but not always the real file in use), PasDocs (gives lot's of information but not dependences themselves), Delphi Unit dependency Scanner (gives only project's root paths).
3. View>DebugWindows>Modules  - Doesn't show anything or I we can not understand how to activate it in the IDE.
4. In later Delphi versions there is a way to run compile with argument --depend. But we were not able to find this functionality in Borland Delphi 5.

Can someone help?